# circe type field not showing

Tags: scala, circe

When encoding to Json with circe we really want the `type` field to show e.g.

```
scala> val fooJson = foo.asJson
fooJson: io.circe.Json =
{
  "this_is_a_string" : "abc",
  "another_field" : 123,
  "type" : "Foo"
}
```

This is taken from the release notes which previously mentions that you can configure the encoding like this:

```
implicit val customConfig: Configuration = 
Configuration.default.withSnakeCaseKeys.withDefaults.withDiscriminator("type")
```

Also other information about circe [here](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2016/01/14/configuring-generic-derivation/) suggests that without any configuration you should get some class type information in the encoding json.

Am I missing something? How do you get the class type to show?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE 30/03/2017: Follow up to OP's comment**

I was able to make this work, as shown in the linked [release notes](https://github.com/circe/circe/releases/tag/v0.6.0-RC1).

Preparation step 1: add additional dependency to build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "io.circe" %% "circe-generic-extras" % "0.7.0"
```

Preparation step 2: setup dummy sealed trait hierarchy

```
import io.circe.{ Decoder, Encoder }
import io.circe.parser._, io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.generic.extras.Configuration
import io.circe.generic.extras.auto._
import io.circe.generic.{ semiauto => boring } // <- This is the default generic derivation behaviour
import io.circe.generic.extras.{ semiauto => fancy } // <- This is the new generic derivation behaviour

implicit val customConfig: Configuration = Configuration.default.withDefaults.withDiscriminator("type")

sealed trait Stuff
case class Foo(thisIsAString: String, anotherField: Int = 13) extends Stuff
case class Bar(thisIsAString: String, anotherField: Int = 13) extends Stuff

object Foo {
  implicit val decodeBar: Decoder[Bar] = fancy.deriveDecoder
  implicit val encodeBar: Encoder[Bar] = fancy.deriveEncoder
}

object Bar {
  implicit val decodeBar: Decoder[Bar] = boring.deriveDecoder
  implicit val encodeBar: Encoder[Bar] = boring.deriveEncoder
}
```

Actual code using this:

```
val foo: Stuff = Foo("abc", 123)
val bar: Stuff = Bar("xyz", 987)

val fooString = foo.asJson.noSpaces
// fooString: String = {"thisIsAString":"abc","anotherField":123,"type":"Foo"}

val barString = bar.asJson.noSpaces
// barString: String = {"thisIsAString":"xyz","anotherField":987,"type":"Bar"}

val bar2 = for{
  json <- parse(barString)
  bar2 <- json.as[Stuff]
} yield bar2
// bar2: scala.util.Either[io.circe.Error,Stuff] = Right(Bar(xyz,987))

val foo2 = for{
  json <- parse(fooString)
  foo2 <- json.as[Stuff]
} yield foo2
// foo2: scala.util.Either[io.circe.Error,Stuff] = Right(Foo(abc,123))
```

So, provided you import the extra dependency (which is where `Configuration` comes from), it looks like it works.

*Finally, as a sidenote, it does seem that there is some disconnection between [Circe's DESIGN.md](https://github.com/circe/circe/blob/master/DESIGN.md) and practice, for which I am actually happy.*

---

**Original answer:**
I am not sure this is supposed to be supported, by design.

Taken from [Circe's DESIGN.md](https://github.com/circe/circe/blob/master/DESIGN.md):

> Implicit scope should not be used for configuration. Lots of people have asked for a way to configure generic codec derivation to use e.g. a type field as the discriminator for sealed trait hierarchies, or to use snake case for member names. argonaut-shapeless supports this quite straightforwardly with a JsonCoproductCodec type that the user can provide implicitly.
>
> I don't want to criticize this approach—it's entirely idiomatic Scala, and it often works well in practice—but I personally don't like using implicit values for configuration, and I'd like to avoid it in circe until I am 100% convinced that there's no alternative way to provide this functionality.
>
> What this means concretely: You'll probably never see an implicit argument that isn't a type class instance—i.e. that isn't a type constructor applied to a type in your model—in circe, and configuration of generic codec derivation is going to be relatively limited (compared to e.g. argonaut-shapeless) until we find a nice way to do this kind of thing with type tags or something similar.

In particular, `customConfig: Configuration` seems to be  exactly the type of argument that the last paragraph refers to (e.g. *an implicit argument that isn't a type class instance*)

I am sure that @travis-brown or any other Circe's main contributors could shed some more light on this, in case there was in fact a way of doing this - and I would be very happy to know it! :)

Comment: It looks like that may have been rescinded. The release notes mentioned above state that this is how you configure it: https://github.com/circe/circe/releases/tag/v0.6.0-RC1

Comment: thanks for the update - this is what I had found and you beat me to answering. One thing to note is that in my case I had to have `import io.circe.generic.extras.auto._` i.e. with the 'extras' in scope or it wouldn't work.