# Pascal case transform for discriminator parsing to enum cases

Tags: scala, scala-3, circe

I have the following JSON:

```json
[{"type": "first_variant", ...}, {"type": "second_variant", ...}]
```

And I want to parse this JSON to an array of `Variant` enums like this:

```scala
enum Variant:
  case FirstVariant(...)
  case SecondVariant(...)
```

How can I do it with `circe`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scala 3 and Circe 0.14.6, you can require a discriminator field in snake case by providing the appropriate `Configuration` and `Codec`:

```
//> using lib io.circe::circe-core:0.14.6
//> using lib io.circe::circe-generic:0.14.6

import io.circe.Codec
import io.circe.syntax.EncoderOps
import io.circe.derivation.Configuration
import io.circe.generic.auto.given

enum Variant:
  case FirstVariant(x: Int)
  case SecondVariant(y: String)

given Configuration =
  Configuration
    .default
    .withDiscriminator("type")
    .withSnakeCaseConstructorNames

given Codec[Variant] =
  Codec.AsObject.derivedConfigured

@main def example =
  val l = List(
    Variant.FirstVariant(1),
    Variant.SecondVariant("hello")
  )
  val lJson = l.asJson
  println(lJson)
  val l2 = lJson.as[List[Variant]].toOption.get
  assert(l2 == l)
```

This outputs:

```json
[
  {
    "x" : 1,
    "type" : "first_variant"
  },
  {
    "y" : "hello",
    "type" : "second_variant"
  }
]
```

References: I derived this example from the [(outdated) Circle documentation on ADTs](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/adt.html#the-future), [the answer to a similar question for Circe 0.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43098011/21927647) and the source code of Circe 0.14.6 ([`Configuration.scala`](https://github.com/circe/circe/blob/1cebca519819805b2fc95be81cd15363f211b8b9/modules/core/shared/src/main/scala-3/io/circe/derivation/Configuration.scala) and [`ConfiguredDerivesSuite.scala`](https://github.com/circe/circe/blob/1cebca519819805b2fc95be81cd15363f211b8b9/modules/tests/shared/src/test/scala-3/io/circe/ConfiguredDerivesSuite.scala)).

Comment: Great answer! I put it here on Scastie to try it out: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/fAbyzaT6T0GQMaMz0LbpJQ/4